# Using R to Rearrange Data

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-science, tidyr

I am working on some data in `R`. For reproducibility, the data is as follows:

```
month,source,amount1,amount2,total
jan,central,200,400,600
jan,tax,100,200,300
jan,fines,100,200,300
jan,east,150,50,200
jan,tax,100,25,125
jan,fine,0,75,75
jan,levies,0,0,0
Jan,tithe,0,0,0
```

Note that the amount for `central` is the sum of `tax` and `fines`. I want to rearrange the data by adding a column that will hold the term central, as follows.

```
month,source,amount1,amount2,total,new_column
jan,tax,100,200,300,central
jan,fines,100,200,300,central
jan,tax,100,25,125,east
jan,fine,0,75,75,east
jan,levies,0,0,0,east
Jan,tithe,0,0,0,east
```

I appreciate any help. Note that the rows are not uniform.

Comment: Maybe just filter out the "central" rows? And add new column "central" for each row?

Comment: HI zx I dont get it. Please see updated example.

Comment: I see, updated example helps. Question: does it always come in same order, 1,2,3,1,2,3, etc. 1 being the source like east, central?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you change the source data, if possible. Fines, tax and central or east seem like data that should not be in the same column. Central or East probably represents location data while Fines and Tax are the source of income.

Comment: Hi Stipe, I was hoping to avoid the long way. But I bet there is no way out.

Comment: I totally understand your resistance. But in my experience better go the long way now than later. Bad data structure is going to bite again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a pattern of row order: "source", "tax", "fine", we can *split* every 3 rows, remove 1st row, add new column from the first row "source" column, then *rbind* the result:

```
do.call(rbind, 
        lapply(split(x, rep(1:(nrow(x)/3), each = 3)), function(i){
          res <- i[2:nrow(i), ]
          res$new_column <- i[1, "source" ]
          res
        }))
#     month source amount1 amount2 total new_column
# 1.2   jan    tax     100     200   300    central
# 1.3   jan  fines     100     200   300    central
# 2.5   jan    tax     100      25   125       east
# 2.6   jan   fine       0      75    75       east
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment. Unfortunately, it is not always in the same order. Let me mix up the example a bit. In some cases, we have more rows than in other cases. See updated example.

Comment: @JohnKaruitha OK, What are all possible sources that needs to go as a new column: central, east, anything else? But the logic is the same, split, remove 1st row, add it as new column.